# Trick from a Novel to find cardinal point

Tags: survival

In Treasure Of Khan by Clive Cussler, the main protagonist is lost in a desert and uses his watch to determine directions, here is the quote :

> An old survival trick, he knew that south must be halfway between the
>   hour hand and twelve o'clock if he was standing in the Northern
>   Hemisphere.

I didn't quite understood it. Is this a real trick ? Is there a name for it ? How does it work ?